# c# label text value is not updating

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I'm trying to change label text on the main form(Form1) from another form(MyForm), but the UI is not updating the label value.

What am i doing wrong?

**MyForm.cs**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Global Global = new Global();
    Global.Hey();
}
```

**Global.cs**

```
public static void Hey()
{
   Form1 MainForm = new Form1();
   MainForm.ChangeLabel();
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
 public void ChangeLabel()
 {
     status_label.Text = "HeyHey";
     MessageBox.Show(status_label.Text);
     // MessageBox : HeyHey, but on UI showing the old value.
 }

 // MyForm open
 private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     MyForm mf = new MyForm();

     if (!mf.Visible)
     {
          mf.Show();
     }
     else
     {
        mf.BringToFront();
     }

 }
```

Comment: This line:  `Form1 MainForm = new Form1();` is creating a _new_ form so that when you call `MainForm.ChangeLabel();` you are changing the label on that new form rather than the form that is currently visible.   Try changing your `Hey` method as follows:  `public static void Hey(Form1 form)` and then inside the method call `form.ChangeLabel(this);` and remove the code that create a form.

Comment: Every time you click the button, you create a new `Form1`, which is separate from the one showing, and change the label on this new, hidden form. To change it on the already showing form, you need a reference to that specific object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a separate, new `Form1` when you click the button on `MyForm`. You need to pass a reference to the existing `Form1` to `MyForm`, such as through the constructor, and change the label on that object.

It should look something like this. This bypasses the `Global` class, since `MyForm` has the reference directly. If you want to keep the `Global` class, you'll have to do something similar, provide `Global` with a reference to `Form1`, and make sure the `Hey` method uses this `Form1` reference. And since you're calling a static method, you don't need to instantiate a new `Global` object beforehand.

**MyForm.cs**

```
private Form1 _form;

public MyForm(Form1 form)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _form = form;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _form.ChangeLabel();
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
 public void ChangeLabel()
 {
     status_label.Text = "HeyHey";
     MessageBox.Show(status_label.Text);
     // MessageBox : HeyHey, but on UI showing the old value.
 }

 // MyForm open
 private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     MyForm mf = new MyForm(this);

     if (!mf.Visible)
     {
          mf.Show();
     }
     else
     {
        mf.BringToFront();
     }

 }
```